# css properties not working for protractor?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I wrote some protractor test for my angularjs application and write some test case for css properties validation but my test case are not working for css properties validation so any one help me on how to test the css properties ?
In my test case i wrote is:

```
element.all(by.css('.detailsFormLabel')).getCssValue('font-family', 'width', 'font-size', 'height', 'color').then(function(cssStyleProperty) {
    expect(cssStyleProperty).toBe['Verdana', 'Verdana', '125px', '11px', '25px', 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)'];
});

element.all(by.css('.detailsFormAttribute')).getCssValue('font-family', 'width', 'font-size', 'height', 'color').then(function(cssStyleProperty) {
    expect(cssStyleProperty).toBe['Verdana Regular', 'Verdana', '150px', '11px', '25px', 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)'];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass a single parameter in the [`getCssValue()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue) method of protractor and you should be using round braces `()` in [expect statements](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Expectations). Check the below example -

```
element.all(by.css('.detailsFormLabel')).getCssValue('font-family').then(function (cssStyleProperty) {
      expect(cssStyleProperty).toBe('Verdana');
});
```

Similarly get other values too. Hope this helps.